# iTextSharp equivalent of XPdfFontOptions

Tags: itext, pdfsharp

I'm converting a C# app page which uses PdfSharp to iTextSharp & have found a line of code I can't see an obvious replacement for.

The existing code is

```
PdfSharp.Drawing.XPdfFontOptions options = new  PdfSharp.Drawing.XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, 
PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
```

Also, what if I want to use other, non-base fonts? I can see from the docs how to create one of the 16 types, however what if I want "Frutiger LT 45 Light"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the examples from [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) [Chapter 11: Choosing the right font](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=11); the .Net versions are available [here](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx).

You'll see that fonts can be selected, configured, and used like this:

```
public const string FONT = "c:/windows/fonts/arialbd.ttf";
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font f = new Font(bf, 12);
document.Add(new Paragraph("Text", f));

Font garamondItalic = FontFactory.GetFont(
  "Garamond", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12, Font.ITALIC
);
document.Add(new Paragraph("Garamond-Italic", garamondItalic));
```

Thus, you explicitly enter the encoding and embedding options in the font creation instead of via some font option object.

BTW, here `BaseFont` does not refer to the *standard 14 fonts* which *shall be available to the conforming reader* according to [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (I assume that you mean those fonts when you talk about *the 16 types*) but instead is a base object from which fonts at given sizes are created.